# basic chart + title using vba for ppt

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to vba. 
I want to generate a ppt with chart and title in it. I am using following code, but having problems. Please suggest.

```
Set pptobj = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pptobj.Visible = TRUE
Set presentn= pptobj.Presentations.Add
Dim dirtemp
dirtemp= CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
Dim tempImg
tempImg = dirtemp+"\test.gif"
Dim cnt
ind = 1
'my chart is in chartobj
if Not IsNull ( chartobj) then
    presentn.Slides.Add ind, 8
    chartobj.ExportPicture tempImg, "gif"        
    presentn.Slides(ind).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "some title"
    presentn.Slides(ind).Shapes(2).AddPicture tempImg, false, true, 50, 50
ind = ind + 1
end if
```

I am using ppLayoutChart (value 8).
However if I use layout = 12 (ppLayoutBlank), I am able to generate the chart successfuly, however there is no way I can add title then :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a blank layout slide, there will be no shapes, so .Shapes(1) will not return anything (it's throwing an error when you refer to it, yes?)

If you need to add a title to a blank slide, you'll have to add a text shape, set its text and format it to taste.

It might be simpler to add a dummy ppLayoutChart slide, set its title text, copy/paste that onto your *real* slide, then delete the dummy slide.  That will ensure that the "pseudo-title" is formatted as it should be.

Or simpler yet, don't add a blank, add a title only layout slide.